# Can a Java class with a Function field be considered Immutable?

Tags: java, immutability, functional-interface

If I have a class with a Function field, is it Immutable? For example:

```
@Immutable
private static final class DependentBigtablePath extends BigtablePath {

 private final BigtablePath delegate;
 private final Function<String, String> derivationFunction;

 private DependentBigtablePath( BigtablePath delegate, Function<String, String> derivationFunction) {
  this.delegate = Preconditions.checkNotNull(delegate);
  this.derivationFunction =Preconditions.checkNotNull(derivationFunction);
 }  
  ...
}
```

We dont know if the Function implementing class is Immutable, but does that matter?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this depends on the interpretation of immutable, as one could argue that changes to internal `Function` state don't modify the function itself (e.g. captured variables), but I would think that _technically_ this does not make the class immutable.

Comment: depends... guava's `@Immutable` explains "The requirement that all reference fields be immutable ensures *deep* immutability, meaning all contained state is also immutable [`Function` violates that] . A weaker property, common with container classes, is *shallow* immutability, which allows some of the object's fields to point to mutable objects. One example of shallow immutability is guava's `ImmutableList`, which may contain mutable elements." - so which one are you trying to achieve? Bad function: `String[] state={""}; Function<String,String> f = in->in+state[0]; state[0] = "oops";`

Answer (score 1):

For a practical definition of "immutable": no, you cannot know whether `DependentBigtablePath` is immutable without knowing whether all of its fields are also immutable. As an obvious example of why this is so:

```
public class ClassThatWantsToBeImmutable {
  public final MutableClass a;

  //...constructor, etc.

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return a.toString();
  }
}
```

If `a` is mutated such that its `toString()` method returns something different, then the behavior of the `ClassThatWantsToBeImmutable` (which references `a`) changes as well.

Comment: I agree that if the Function changes, so that any method using it gives a different result, then the object is not imutable. I just needed to think through what is means to be immutable.